# Magento: addAttributeToFilter to list Empty Multi Select Attribute

Tags: magento

For a Multi Select attribute, how can I filter a product collection to find products where the attribute has nothing selected? I have tried the following, but none of them worked:

```
$productCollection->addAttributeToFilter( 'multi_select_attribute', array( 'null' => true ) );
$productCollection->addAttributeToFilter( 'multi_select_attribute', array( 'null' => '' ) );
$productCollection->addAttributeToFilter( 'multi_select_attribute', array( 'eq' => '' ) ); 
$productCollection->addAttributeToFilter( 'multi_select_attribute', array( 'finset' => '') );
```

All return an empty collection.

So, how can I filter the product collection to find products where the 'multi_select_attribute' has nothing selected?

EDIT - Additional Information:

This is what I'm doing:

```
$productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($productCollection);
$productCollection->addStoreFilter();
$productCollection->addAttributeToFilter( ... one of the above ... );
```

Comment: array( 'notnull' => '' ) seems to list all products which have a value, but array( 'null' => '' ) returns an empty list!

Comment: is it the only filter you are adding to your collection? can you please provide more code?

Comment: will anything change if you comment out line with `_addProductAttributesAndPrices`?

Comment: notnull = false? Maybe finset => array('value'=>null)?

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at `catalog_product_entity_varchar` you'll see that only values actually filled for a product's multiselect attribute are filled there.

That means that if no value is selected for a product, nothing is written in DB for that product/multiselect attribute which means that you'll have at least to make some sort of join or something to retrieve product with no value.

A quick and dirty way to do that is to first get products with a value for this multiselect attribute, and then take them back from the original collection:

```
$attribute_code = 'multi_select_attribute';

// Get a product collection and add whatever filters you have to
$collectionWithMultiSelectValue = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collectionWithMultiSelectValue->addAttributeToSelect($attribute_code)
->addFieldToFilter(array( array('attribute'=> $attribute_code, 'notnull' => true)));

// Take products with a value for the attribute off the collection
$productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('nin' => $collectionWithMultiSelectValue->getAllIds()));
```